# XML Report Processing - Formats of XML Files

Tags: xml, teamcity, automated-tests

I'm rather new to TeamCity- so I've following request:

I'd like to generate XML files, which should contain results of a test run (name of the test, time, state), in the correct format, so that they are compatible with TeamCity.
Following link [0] tells me that I can provide such XML files to TeamCity and some third party tools would preprocess that for TeamCity- so those files will be picked up and a graphical representation of the content will be made?

So, my concrete question is, how I can find the specific structure of the XML tags, so that TeamCity can read it? (or whats the best way to generate such XML files)

Thx a lot in advance!

[0] https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/XML+Report+Processing

Answer (score 0):

It is the other way round: the tools named on this page (JUnit, trx, Findbugs and others) are producing their output in xml files in their own format. TeamCity on its side, consumes and understands these files. this can result in tests being reported to the ui (for example for junit/surefire/trx), or the custom repor page added to the build

Comment: That was clear to me, but my question was how a structure of some of those generated files looks like. I don't want to use any third party tool (if this is possible?).
I want to generate the xml files on my own, so that TeamCity could read it- so I need to know the structure of tags.